# SPARQL same predicates with different values

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am using SPARQL to query my data from the triplestore.
In the triplestore I have a form containing a table, the table has different table entries. Each entry has a number of predicates. I want to use the predicates index and cost. My query needs to catch the first 2 rows, indices 0 and 1 and save the cost under a specific variable for each.

So I have tried the following (prefix ext is ommited) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?entry ?priceOne ?priceTwo
  WHERE {
    ?form ext:table ?table.
    ?table ext:entry ?entry.
    ?entry ext:index 0;
       ext:cost ?priceOne.
    ?entry ext:index 1;
       ext:cost ?priceTwo.
}
```

This however does not show any values, if I remove the second part (with index 1) than I do get ?priceOne. How can I get both values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query finds each `?entry` that has *both* `ext:index` values, 0 and 1. You could avoid this by using something like `?entry0` and `?entry1`, essentially duplicating your triple patterns.

But typically, you would [match alternatives](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives) with `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?entry ?priceOne ?priceTwo
WHERE {

    # a shorter way to specify this, if you don’t need the ?table variable
    ?form ext:table/ext:entry ?entry .

    {
      ?entry ext:index 0 ;
             ext:cost ?priceOne .
    }
    UNION
    {
      ?entry ext:index 1 ;
             ext:cost ?priceTwo .
    }

}
```

Comment: entry0 and entry1 solution is what I actually want. I didn't think of that, used it and that is exactly what I wanted, thank you